# Why is CSS design file not showing up properly?

Tags: html, css, webserver, apache2

I have an Raspberrypi with apache2 installed. I have two files stored in:

> /var/www/html

the one file is "index.html" and the other one is "design.css"

This is the file "index.html" (it´s written in German, but I think only the html tags are important)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="./design.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="rot">Hallo und herzlich wilkommen auf meiner Webseite!</h1>
    <p>Hier steht text</p>
    <hr></hr>
    <bold>Hier sind Audiodateien:</bold><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the file "design.css"

```
.rot {
    color: "red";
}

p {
    color: "blue";
}
```

I want my first text shown in red, and the second one in blue.

But when I open my website, the text only shows up in black, and not as supposed in color.

I hope I described my problem well so you may help me

Comment: Typo: CSS colours are keywords, not strings, they should not have quotes around them.

Comment: Use [a CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Comment: Also no need for the `./` if in same dir

Comment: Also use a [markup validator](https://validator.nu/) as you are missing a doctype, the end tag for the `hr` element is forbidden, and there is no `bold` element in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u sure u have ever even read the syntax? Though yes many people get confused with href and src attributes. Now back to the problem, the problem is with the link tag.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link src="./design.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="rot">Hallo und herzlich wilkommen auf meiner Webseite!</h1>
    <p>Hier steht text</p>
    <hr></hr>
    <bold>Hier sind Audiodateien:</bold><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

U dont have to use href in link tag but src attribute. Hope this helps. And also if it still not works, that maybe because of caching. It happens many times that the changes you make aren't visible because browser has cached the CSS file. To solve it, open the inspect element with Ctrl + Shift + I, now long press the reload button and choose hard reload. If it still not works then I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the quotation marks that are setting you back